# Keeping banner image centred when window resized?

Tags: html, css, image, banner

I have a issue with a banner I'm trying to use for my website. The image is 1960px x 196px. Here is my code. I just can't figure it out. I'm trying to make it so the image crops itself when you resize the browser, therefore keeping the image in the center.

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
        <nav><center><div class="logo"></div></center></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://614reborn.com/forum/forum.php">Forum</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://614reborn.com/webclient.html">Play Now</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://614reborn.com/download.html">Download</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://614reborn.com/donate/">Donate</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Nav-wrapper:

```
#nav-wrapper {
margin: 0px auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
background-position:no-repeat;
```

logo:

```
.logo {
background: url('../img/logo.png') no-repeat 0 0;
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
width: 1960px;
height: 196px;
```

Please somebody help with this issue, its been irritating me for a while now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css :

```
.logo { 
        max-width: 1960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: 196px;

 }

 #nav-wrapper { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: I'm trying to make it so the image crops itself when you resize the browser, therefore keeping the image in the center. Sorry I didn't explain the issue properly in the question. I tried this and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
    align='center'
```

hope this helps :)